# Understanding gap in Cesiumjs bar chart?

Tags: javascript, cesium

I use Cesiumjs to create a bar chart.  I don't understand why there is a gap in the bar? [Code Link](https://bit.ly/2MnjQH3)

[image]

```
        var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
        viewer.scene.globe.depthTestAgainstTerrain = true;
        var alt = 0;
        var height = 1204.5894586894588;
        var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
            name: "1",
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-122, 37.5, alt),
            box: {
                dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(4000 / 20.0, 3000.0 / 20, height),
                material: Cesium.Color.YELLOW
            }
        });
        alt += height;
        height = 1141.9837105171814;
        var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
            name: "2",
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-122, 37.5, alt),
            box: {
                dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(4000 / 20.0, 3000.0 / 20, height),
                material: Cesium.Color.BLUE
            }
        });
        alt += height;
        height = 1676.1912919343326;
        var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
            name: "3",
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-122, 37.5, alt),
            box: {
                dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(4000 / 20.0, 3000.0 / 20, height),
                material: Cesium.Color.RED
            }
        });
        alt += height;
        height = 1199.65;

        var blueBox = viewer.entities.add({
            name: "4",
            position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-122, 37.5, alt),
            box: {
                dimensions: new Cesium.Cartesian3(4000 / 20.0, 3000.0 / 20, height),
                material: Cesium.Color.GRREN
            }
        });
        viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
        /*var outlineOnly = viewer.entities.add({
         name : 'Yellow box outline',
         position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-100.0, 40.0, 300000.0),
         box : {
         dimensions : new Cesium.Cartesian3(400000.0, 300000.0, 500000.0),
         fill : false,
         outline : true,
         outlineColor : Cesium.Color.YELLOW
         }
         });*/

        viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the position property should be the center of the cubes. Try with

```
Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-122, 37.5, alt+height/2)
```

as position